# Formatar valor recebido no JSON C#

Tags: javascript, jquery

Após retornar o valor para o meu formulário, quero formatar ele de forma a mostrar as casas decimais corretamente. Já fiz várias tentativas usando o jQuery Mask, mais não tive sucesso. Agradeço se alguém poder ajudar.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {



            $("#categoriaPrecificacao").change(function () {

                var categoria_selecionada = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

                var urlCompleto = "/Estacionar/ObterValorHoraPrecificacao/";

                $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: "GET",
                    url: urlCompleto,
                    data: { id: categoria_selecionada },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data["results"].valorHora);
                        $(".ValorHora").val(data["results"].valorHora);
                        $('.ValorHora').mask('#.##0,00', { reverse: true });
                    }
                });

            });


        });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: um dúvida, o script é mesmo aplicado? não tem erros no console certo?

Comment: @RicardoPontual, não tem erro, a resposta está vindo corretamente

Comment: @RicardoPontual, já encontrei uma solução, mesmo assim agradeço

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi retornar o valor para a view já formatado.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet, ActionName("ObterValorHoraPrecificacao")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ObterValorHoraPrecificacao(Guid id)
{
    var dados = _mapper.Map<PrecificacaoViewModel>(await _precificacaoRepository.ObterPorId(id));
    var valorFormatado = string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:C}", dados.ValorHora).Replace("R","").Replace("$","");

    return Json(new
    {
        results = valorFormatado
    });

}
```

Jquery

```
    $("#categoriaPrecificacao").change(function () {

        var categoria_selecionada = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

        var urlCompleto = "/Estacionar/ObterValorHoraPrecificacao/";

        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            method: "GET",
            url: urlCompleto,
            data: { id: categoria_selecionada },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data["results"]);
                $(".ValorHora").val(data["results"]);

            }
        });

    });
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito bem, ia falar a mesma coisa. Só vi que na sua formatação você faz um replace dos caracteries "R$", o C# ja formata para você também em formato numérico apenas, basta no ligar de usar o ```C``` como formato, usar o ```N```, irá formatar do mesmo jeito porém sem o **R$**. Poderia ser feito assim ```var valorFormatado = dados.ValorHora.ToString("N2", new CultureInfo("pt-br"))```. Mais em suma o resultado seria o mesmo

Comment: @RobsonSilva, vou usar a sua dica, valeu!